# Protect from getting IIS physical path credentials in plain text (using powershell)

Tags: windows, security, iis, powershell

Each of my websites configured in IIS use a special local user to access the website folder (*Physical Path Credentials*) located on the server.

To my knowlege it isn't possible to view the passwords of these local users (which is a good thing). It is only possible to change the password, of course.

But with powershell I can do this:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
foreach ($site in $Websites) {
  "Site: " + $site.name + " - " + 
  "User: " + $site.userName + 
  "PW: " + $site.password  
}
```

Is there a way to protect the user password so that such a query is not possible or won't retrieve the passwords?

I know Administrator rights are necessary to execute this command but IMHO it shouldn't be possible to read out passwords like that even then.

Comment: It might be a silly observation, but you need administrator privileges to do what you are showing there. This is not going to work in normal situations.

Comment: Being and admin does not generally give you access to passwords.  I understand your point, but the question is a really good one.

Comment: @Mike: That is exactly what i mean - Since posting this question I searched a little more but haven't found anything useful yet... Do you think it is generally possible to prevent admins from performing such a query (but not forbid using powershell in general)?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that.  I wish I did.  Maybe someone will provide an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a Microsoft representative in our office about a year ago and I asked the same question. The answer I got was that this is the way it is and there is no other way to protect this since you need an Administrator account to access this information.

Comment: Since I haven't got any other info on this, I will accept the answer, although it's not really satisfying...